# Expand div height based on ul li elements?

Tags: html, css

Peace and blessing be upon you :)

Say I have:

```
<div class="c1">
   <div class="c2">
      <ul>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
         <li><div class="c3"></div></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

So Basically I want the `div` c1 & c2 to expand based on `li` contents.

I have created this Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unpfk1aw/ which in `c1` expand but `c2` stays still. I would really appreciate if you tell me what is the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `float: left;`. This takes the element out of the flow of the document, and means the `c2` div has no idea about each `li`'s height.

Instead, replace `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;` in your `ul li` selector.